# Find a cubic monic integral coefficient whose discriminant is $-83$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I trie to calculate the Hilbert class field of $\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt{-83}\right)$, whose class number is $3$, so I should find a cubic integral monic polynomial whose discriminant is $-83$, but I failed

Comment: Please use TeX on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no guarantee that such a polynomial exists, because the corresponding cubic subfield of the Hilbert class field need not be monogenic. But it does actually exist in this case and one example is

$$x^3 - x^2 + x - 2$$

A really useful website for looking up polynomials whose corresponding number field  has small discriminant and/or constrained ramification is this one:

https://hobbes.la.asu.edu/NFDB/

You can find the polynomial above by setting the degree to be $3$ and the the number of ramified primes to be 1 with smallest and largest prime $83$.

You can of course find the same field using Kummer theory but it would be a slow process.

Comment: What ? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Comment: @F.C. are you objecting to "because the corresponding cubic subfield of the Hilbert class field need not be monogenic"? The primitive element theorem refers to the generator of a field; monogenic refers to the generator of the ring of integers; no contradiction there.

Comment: This tool is really useful,thanks a lot !

Comment: @F.C. What ? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansplaining